# Defining a hardcoded Javascript function dynamically

Tags: javascript, function

I am programming a web frontend for a database application. I have several function calls in the html body, like:

```
<input type=button value="Set 1" id="btn1" onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","title")>
<input type=button value="Set 2" id="btn2" onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","name")>
<input type=button value="Set 3" id="btn3" onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","gender")>

function edit_entry(src, action, arg1) {
  alert(src.onclick);
  src.onclick = function () { edit_entry( src, action, arg1 };
  alert(src.onclick);
}
```

When clicked on "btn1", the first alert returns the hardcoded function definition: `function onclick(event) { edit_entry(this,"edit","title") }`

But the second alert returns the function definition with variables `function onclick(event) { edit_entry(src, action, arg1) }`

So when these variables change later the function does get the wrong values.  How can I apply the content of the variables to the function definition instead of the variables itself so that the definition is again `function onclick(event) { edit_entry(this,"edit","title") }` ?

P.S.: I know that this code snippet makes no sense as it shall only describe my problem as simple as possible.

---

Here is my code I was referring to. I hope this all makes more sense now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

HTML Body:

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="group_1_button_edit" class="action_element" onClick=edit_entries(this,"edit","artnr","artalt","bez1","bez2","bez3")>
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="group_9_button_edit" class="action_element" onClick=edit_entries(this,"edit","dok1","dok2","dok3","dok4","dok5")>
```

The values behind "edit" are the IDs of the input textboxes the content will be read from.

```
function edit_entries(caller,action,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5,opt6,opt7,opt8,opt9,opt10,opt11,opt12) {

caller_id = caller.id.split("_");
id = caller_id[1];

switch(action) {
    case "edit":

        //Making textboxes writeable for changing values
        //[...]

        document.getElementById("group_"+id+"_button_edit").value="Save";
        document.getElementById("group_"+id+"_button_edit").onclick=function(){ edit_entries(this,"save",opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5,opt6,opt7,opt8,opt9,opt10,opt11,opt12); };
    break;
    case "save":
        if (confirm("Datensatz wirklich aktualisieren?")) {
            artnr_key = XML_OBJ.getElementsByTagName("artnr")[0].textContent;

            string = "";
            //Building the AJAX Request String: textbox id = value
            url = 'mysql_req_n1.php?type=edit_entries&'+string;
            send_request(url);
        }
    break;
}
}

//called by AJAX handler
function edit_entries_unlock() {

//Getting "id" by value check
counter_a = 1;
while (counter_a <= 9) {
    if (document.getElementById("group_"+counter_a+"_button_edit").value == "Save") id = counter_a;
    counter_a++;
}


//Getting textbox IDs located in the AJAX response
opts = XML_OBJ.getElementsByTagName("opts")[0].textContent;
options = opts.split(",");

//Making textboxes readonly again
//[...]

document.getElementById("group_"+id+"_button_edit").value="Edit";
document.getElementById("group_"+id+"_button_edit").onclick=function(){ edit_entries(this,"edit",options[0],options[1],options[2],options[3],options[4],options[5],options[6],options[7],options[8],options[9],options[10],options[11]); };

}
```

And that is what happens:

I click on the first button (group_1_button_edit). It jumps to the switch block "edit" making the textboxes writable and changing the edit button to a save button. Works fine.

I click on save. The switch block "save" builds the request string and starts the ajax request.

The ajax handler starts edit_entries_unlock() when the response is there. Part of the XML Response are the textbox IDs I have used before. The onclick function gets changed again to an "edit" function with the corresponding textbox IDs from the XML object.

Now I click on the second button "group_9_button_edit". Everything is working like mentioned above. No problems. The textboxes of group 9 unlock, get saved und locked again as wanted.

But now the bug: I click on the first button again "group_1_button_edit" which now uses the changed function definition. It starts the switch block "edit" but with the values of the textbox IDs of GROUP 9 (which I edited before) and not GROUP 1.

I guess it has something to do with the variables opt1-opt12. They always contain the values of the last "edit_entries_unlock()" run. And as all the edited function definitions uses opt1-opt12 as well they start with the values of the last run and not with the values I used when recreating the function definition.

For that reason I asked how to build a function definition with the content of variables during the function creation process instead of the content during the execution process.

I hope that makes a lot more sense now. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking 100%. But as I understood, you can store `src`, `action` and `arg1` variables in temporary variables at the top of the function. Then when you define the `onclick` function again, use those temporary variables instead of `src`, `action` and `arg1`.

Comment: Well, yeah, it makes no sense that you assign an `onclick` event handler inside an `onclick` event handler... Which variables are changing when where to what exactly?

Comment: Probably the first thing to note (and fix) is that that HTML is **invalid** because of the onclicks: `onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","title")` . The value of an attribute [must be in quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) if it contains any spaces, `'`, `"`, `>`, `/`, or `=` characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very bad way to pass data.

You should avoid using inline code

```
<input type=button value="Set 1" id="btn1" onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","title")>
<input type=button value="Set 2" id="btn2" onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","name")>
<input type=button value="Set 3" id="btn3" onClick=edit_entry(this,"edit","gender")>
```

Should be

```
<input type=button value="Set 1" id="btn1" data-field-name="title">
<input type=button value="Set 2" id="btn2" data-field-name="name">
<input type=button value="Set 3" id="btn3" data-field-name="gender">
<script>
(function(){  // or use on load event

    // define the click function
    var clickFunction = function(event){  
        // get the element data
        var fieldName = event.target.attributes["data-field-name"].value;
        // do what you need to do.....
    }

    // query the DOM to get the elements you are after.
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    // iterate them and add the event handler to each.
    for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
         el[i].addEventListener("click",clickFunction,false);
    }
})();
</script>
```

As for what you are trying to do in the example you gave I have no clue so maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You onclick handler creates a **closure**. So, the values `src`, `action` and `arg1` in the below (from your edit_entry function) will be what it was at the time this function was created / recreated (the latter for when you click it the next time)

```
src.onclick = function () { edit_entry( src, action, arg1 };
```

You'd be able to modify these only within the same method (or it's child methods). Note that since you set the onclick to the above you are basically passing around the same variables into the handler the next time it is clicked.

Any changes you are seeing for these variables would be from within your onclick handler (and not external to it)

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the help of T.J.Crowder I was able to fix the code.
The line that I needed to fix was

```
options = opts.split(",");
```

to

```
var options = opts.split(",");
```

I didn't know that declaring variables inside a function without `var` would make them a part of the window object and therefore making it a global variable. So my closure was accessing a global variable instead a local one.

One small word, but with big impact.