# Javascript closures and global variables

Tags: javascript, closures

I am just learning how closures work and started playing with some code. To my understanding closures are some kind of memory which saves the environment of the function at that state the closure was created and is still alive (when returned or bound to an event) even when the parent function has ended.

So I tried the code below which is working as expected. Two buttons which switch their corresponding textboxes from "check" to "saved".

```js
//var v1;
//var v2;
//var v3;

function func1(src, action, arg) {
  document.getElementById(arg).value = "check";
  document.getElementById(src.id).onclick = function() {
    func2(src, action, arg);
  };
  //v1 = src;
  //v2 = action;
  //v3 = arg;
}

function func2(v1, v2, v3) {
  document.getElementById(v3).value = "saved";
  document.getElementById(v1.id).onclick = function() {
    func1(v1, v2, v3);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="t1">
<input type=button id="btn1" value="Go 1" onclick="func1(this, 'edit', 't1')">
<input type=text id="t2">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Go 2" onclick="func2(this, 'edit', 't2')">
```

But now comes the confusion. When I use globals to construct the closure in func2() the switches bug around. See code below:

```js
var v1;
var v2;
var v3;

function func1(src, action, arg) {
  document.getElementById(arg).value = "check";
  document.getElementById(src.id).onclick = function() {
    func2();
  };
  v1 = src;
  v2 = action;
  v3 = arg;
}

function func2() {
  document.getElementById(v3).value = "saved";
  document.getElementById(v1.id).onclick = function() {
    func1(v1, v2, v3);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="t1">
<input type=button id="btn1" value="Go 1" onclick="func1(this,'edit','t1')">
<input type=text id="t2">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Go 2" onclick="func2(this,'edit','t2')">
```

Click on Go1 -> Textbox1 = check; Click on Go2 -> Textbox2 = check; But now click on Go1 -> Textbox2 (instead of 1) = saved.

So it seems that the variables v1, v2, v3 in the closure still uses the global values outside the closure. Can somebody please explain why and what to do so it works with globals?

---

Thanks to T.J.Crowder I updated my code to use private variables in the closures. But unfortunately it still does not work. Same behaviour like the second code block.

```js
var v1;
var v2;
var v3;

function func1(src, action, arg) {
  document.getElementById(arg).value = "check";
  document.getElementById(src.id).onclick = function() {
    func2();
  };
  v1 = src;
  v2 = action;
  v3 = arg;
}

function func2() {
  var private1 = v1;
  var private2 = v2;
  var private3 = v3;

  document.getElementById(private3).value = "saved";
  document.getElementById(private1.id).onclick = function() {
    func1(private1, private2, private3);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="t1">
<input type=button id="btn1" value="Go 1" onclick="func1(this,'edit','t1')">
<input type=text id="t2">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Go 2" onclick="func2(this,'edit','t2')">
```

Comment: *"...in func2() the switches bug around"* Huh?

Comment: The second code block should behave the same way the first code block does. But it does not.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It should behave the way it behaves.

Comment: Sorry.. I deleted my comment because I see it now. Anyway, the thing to understand is that closures capture the variables themselves. Semantically they behave as a sort of private global variables that's only exposed to all the functions declared in the same scope but invisible to functions defined outside of a shared scope.

Comment: @Smithy: I've extended my answer to address what I think may be the central misunderstanding here, that closures have a reference to the variables/arguments for the context where they were created, not a copy of their values. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help. I guess I'll need some minutes to work through your post :)

Comment: @Smithy: Please look at this [helpful tutorial on scope in JavaScript](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/). IMO, this it is better to get aware of the fundamentals of scoping first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it seems that the variables v1, v2, v3 in the closure still uses the global values outside the closure

Right, because nothing is shadowing them, so that's how they end up getting resolved.

In your first code block, the `onclick` handlers are using the `src`, `action`, and `arg` arguments supplied in the call to `func1` and the `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` arguments supplied in the call to `func2`.

In the second example, since you removed the arguments to `func2`, the only reason those identifiers are in scope for the `onclick` function it creates is because of the globals; if it weren't for the globals, you'd be getting `ReferenceError`s because those identifiers would be unresolvable. So it's the globals that get used.

If you passed arguments to `func2` in your second example that had the same names (not a great idea, but just for the sake of explanation), then the identifiers used by the `onclick` closure it creates would resolve against those arguments instead of against the globals.

It may be useful to explain what this line is doing:

```
document.getElementById(v1.id).onclick = function () { func1(v1,v2,v3); };
```

that line creates a function, which is a closure over the context in which it was created, the call to `func2` (and that context refers to the context in which it was created, and so on up to the global context). The `onclick` closure doesn't have a *copy* of the variables that were in scope when it was created, it has an *enduring reference* to them. So when the function gets run, it's the value of the variables **at that moment** that gets used. In your first example, those values never change, because they're the values of the arguments passed to `func2` during the call that created the closure, and nothing ever changes those. In your second example, though, those values are different because you're using the global variables, not the arguments passed to `func2`.

Because the closure has a reference to the context where it was created, the context of *each call* to `func2` is preserved by the closure created within that call. So if the closures created by multiple calls are kept, multiple contexts are kept for the calls to `func2`, and so multiple copies of the arguments are kept (each used by the closure created for that context). A simpler example may help:

```js
// A global variable
var global = "g";

// A function that creates and returns a closure
function foo(arg) {
    return function() {
        snippet.log("global = " + global +) ", arg = " + arg);
    };
}

// Create a closure over arg = 42
var f1 = foo(42);
f1(); // global = g, arg = 42

// Change global
global = "g+";
f1(); // global = g+, arg = 42

// Create a second closure over a second arg, 67
var f2 = foo(67);
f2(); // global = g+, arg = 67

// Change global again
global = "g++";
f1(); // global = g++, arg = 42
f2(); // global = g++, arg = 67
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note how each closure has its own copy of `arg`, but they both share `global`.

This snippet demonstrates that what the closure has is a reference to `arg`, not a *copy* of its value:

```js
function foo(arg) {
  return {
    showArg: function() {
      console.log("arg = " + arg);
    },
    incrementArg: function() {
      ++arg;
    }
  };
}
var o1 = foo(42);
o1.showArg(); // arg = 42
o1.incrementArg();
o1.showArg(); // arg = 43
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

You may find this article on my anemic little blog useful: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

---

Here's a snippet that demonstrates capturing the then-current globals in the closure calling `func2`, but we end up just duplicating what we already have in `src`, `action`, and `arg`, so there's no point.

```js
var v1;
var v2;
var v3;

function func1(src, action, arg) {
  var p1 = src, p2 = action, p3 = arg; // Just duplicates what we already have
  document.getElementById(arg).value = "check";
  document.getElementById(src.id).onclick = function() {
    func2(p1, p2, p3); // We could just use src, action, and arg here like your first example
  };
  v1 = src;
  v2 = action;
  v3 = arg;
}

function func2(v1, v2, v3) {
  document.getElementById(v3).value = "saved";
  document.getElementById(v1.id).onclick = function() {
    func1(v1, v2, v3);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="t1">
<input type=button id="btn1" value="Go 1" onclick="func1(this,'edit','t1')">
<input type=text id="t2">
<input type=button id="btn2" value="Go 2" onclick="func1(this,'edit','t2')">
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. By "enduring reference" you mean that the memory used by the variable does not get flushed when the variable gets used by a closure? Is there a way to get a private copy of a global? I tried to set new variables inside func2() like "private1 = v1" and use "private1" in the closure but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Smithy: The memory occupied by the variable isn't released (is that what you meant by flushed?) until nothing has a reference to it anymore. The variable exists in an object called a *variable binding object* which is part of the *execution context* of the call to `func2`. Closures created within the context get a reference to that object. As long as the closure exists, that object exists, and the variables/arguments/etc. within it exist.

Comment: @Smithy: *"Is there a way to get a private copy of a global? I tried to set new variables inside func2() like "private1 = v1" and use "private1" in the closure but that doesn't work."* That does work, it's a common technique. You might want to try that experiment again, probably just a typo somewhere.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: nice explanation to the fictional mystery going on here!! :)

Comment: @Smithy: If you *literally* did `private1 = v1;` inside `func2`, then the problem was that you fell prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by leaving off `var`. But `var private1 = v1;` in `func2` and then using `private1` in the onclick would work.

Comment: I extended my first post with your solution. But it still does not work. The private variables still get changed during runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: HHhhmmm, when I click "Go1" then "Go2" and then "Go1" again the textbox of "Go2" changes like the code from the second block. Strange.

Comment: @Smithy: Sorry, it's because your closure is calling `func2`. So we'd want to capture that information in the *closure*, not `func2`; in fact, we'd want to capture it in `func1` (which, of course, already has it). (This is *really* strange code; just toggling a value in a checkbox can be a lot simpler than this if it's the end goal.) I've added a snippet at the end that does that, but really, your first example works, so why change it?

Comment: The code above is just an example for a problem I have in a frontend application. I need to use globals in func2 because the data used in that function and in the closure creation comes from a global AJAX XML Object. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069165/defining-a-hardcoded-javascript-function-dynamically) is my first post but its a little bit more complicated. But thank you. You already helped me a lot. I guess I can figure out the rest of the myth by myself. I don't want to take all your time ;)

Comment: Yeeeha after 2 days I was able to fix my frontend code. As you mentioned above I needed to put `var` in front of my private variable used in the closure. One f***ing word messed it all up.... =) Time to read that "Horror of Implicit Globals" entry. Thank you again.